# How to pass String through from JTextArea to drawString without getting nullpointer

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am currently doing a uni assignment as a fresher so I'm not very experienced with coding.

The assignment is to allow the user to create a class diagram. Currently I have a secondary frame that the user inputs a UML design of the class in a JTextArea and then this should be passed through to my GUI by taking what the user wrote and drawing the string (drawString) onto the created class.

Currently I am getting a nullpointerexception when trying to get the String from the JTextArea to drawString and I don't understand this because surely inputUML.getText() would be a String so should be able to be passed through?

This is the class that I am trying to pass the string into

```
package main;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import classdesign.ClassCreation;



public class GroupCreateClass {
private double x;
private double y;
private double r;
private String message;
private String classdesign;


public GroupCreateClass(double x, double y, double r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    makeRectangles(g);
    deleteBox(g);
    userdesignofclass(g);
}

public void makeRectangles(Graphics g) {

        g.drawRect((int)Math.round(x-r),(int)Math.round(y-r),
            (int)Math.round(325.0*r),(int)Math.round(350.0*r));

        g.drawRect((int)Math.round(x-r),(int)Math.round(y-r),
            (int)Math.round(325.0*r),(int)Math.round(19.5*r));

}

public void deleteBox(Graphics g) {

        g.fillRect((int)Math.round(x-r),(int)Math.round(y-r),
            (int)Math.round(19.5*r),(int)Math.round(19.5*r));
}

public void userdesignofclass(Graphics g){

    message = new String("Class");
    g.drawString(message,(int)Math.round(x+140),(int)Math.round(y+15));

    classdesign = (String.valueOf(inputUML.getText())); // This is the code that is giving me a nullpointerexception. I don't understand why, as surely inputUML.getText() should be a String...?
    g.drawString(classdesign,(int)Math.round(x+200), (int)Math.round(y+15));//
}


public double distanceTo(double x, double y) {
    return (Math.abs(this.x-x) + Math.abs(this.y-y));
}

public void update(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


}
```

This is the class that has the JTextArea, it is in another class and package, but the class that should be retrieving the string Extends this class.

```
 package classdesign;
 import java.awt.*;

 import javax.swing.*;

 public class ClassCreation extends JFrame {

private JFrame frame;
private JLabel instructionlabel;
protected JTextArea inputUML; //This is the JTextArea containing the text that I am trying to pass through.
private JButton create;

public void initGUI(){

   frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setSize(325, 350);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setTitle("Class Design - Fill in Class UML");

   JPanel CreationPanel = new JPanel();
   CreationPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

   inputUML = new JTextArea("Write UML here");
   inputUML.setLineWrap(true);
   inputUML.setWrapStyleWord(true);
   CreationPanel.add(new JScrollPane(inputUML),BorderLayout.CENTER);
   CreationPanel.add(inputUML,BorderLayout.CENTER);

   Create = new JButton("Create Class");
   CreationPanel.add(Create,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   //Create.addActionListener(this);


   frame.add(CreationPanel);
 }

 public Frame getFrame() {
       return frame;
   }



 }
```

So what I want to know, simply, is how I can fix that, is there just a line I'm going wrong? or do I have a massive logic problem in what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks :)

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Sorry, I think I've fixed that now.

Comment: Fixed what now?  Even from the code I can see before scrolling, attributes `instructionlabel` should be `instructionLabel`, `CreationPanel` should be `creationPanel` & `Create` should be `create`.  Refer to the JLS for [Java nomenclature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) on class, method & attribute names for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is that it's quite possible you haven't instantiated `inputUML` [ostensibly by calling `initGUI()`] before calling `strings()` [which is a terrible name for a method].

But your problems go far deeper than this. This use of inheritance is completely wrong. [Favor composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). The [use of Magic Numbers is not recommended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants). The variable names are poor (Java is case sensitive, btw. uml is not the same as UML)...do yourself a favor and start browsing [Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) and [Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678). Also consider [Test Driven Development by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) I know you think you don't have the time, but it's much harder to unlearn bad habits than take a little extra time at the beginning to build good ones.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information, and yes, I don't know what I was thinking calling that method strings(), I'll change it.